# odoo / OpenERP V8 - template lost for the QWEB reports

Tags: templates, styles, report, odoo, qweb

system:
Odoo V8.

Issue:
On The last **PDF order** i discovered that somehow **the template is not applied**. (only flat ugly text)
All the fields are here, including footer **but the header is not here and there is no style applied nor pictures** (as it was by default in the previous reports)
**The same occurred for all the PDF reports** so i guess i somehow changed or killed the template. How may i fix it?

Before:
After the install everything was correct. The base template was applied and was ok for both sales and purchase PDF files.

UPDATE: 
The content of the model in the company setting (settings=>company under the report tab) is correct (when i preview the page everything is ok)

The external_layout qview is :

```html
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="report.external_layout">
    <!-- Multicompany -->
    <t t-if="o and 'company_id' in o">
        <t t-set="company" t-value="o.company_id"/>
    </t>
    <t t-if="not o or not 'company_id' in o">
        <t t-set="company" t-value="res_company"/>
    </t>

    <t t-call="report.external_layout_header"/>
    <t t-raw="0"/>
    <t t-call="report.external_layout_footer"/>
</t>
```

The external_layout_header qview is (we can clearly see the call to the RML header which is what is expected):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<t t-name="report.external_layout_header">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % company.logo" style="max-height: 45px;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:20px;" t-field="company.rml_header1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row zero_min_height">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div t-field="company.partner_id" t-field-options="{&quot;widget&quot;: &quot;contact&quot;, &quot;fields&quot;: [&quot;address&quot;, &quot;name&quot;], &quot;no_marker&quot;: true}" style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</t>
```

Both footer and header seem included. but the result of all the PDF reports is:
- no header
- content ok (but no font nor style)
- footer ok (but no font nor style)

Thank you

Comment: when i remove the call for the footer in external_layout then it is not displayed on the reports. That means external_layout is correctly called as a template.

Comment: whatever i change in external_layout_header does nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out that my issue was similar to this one : https://github.com/odoo/odoo/issues/1105

It is due to the web.base.url value which was different depending working from a place or another. then I just fixed it to the most common value and will have to forget working from some computers with tunneling. 
Check the details to fixed the value : https://bugs.launchpad.net/openobject-server/+bug/1295022

Answer (score 0):

Hello Stephane TAMPIGNY,

Plase read this post

[Click to See the Answer for your questioned post  References](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808985/how-to-update-default-header-in-pdf-report-qweb/29814179#29814179)

I hope this should helpful for you ..:)

Comment: Hello,Thank you for the answer. I checked the link. My template is ok in the company settings. but it is not applied. I will check the QView for external report and check if the QView is ok.

Comment: have check the same with new database ??

Comment: Yes. You can check my answer to the issue. It was related to the web.base.url