# How to create a custom header and footer in Qweb Reports in Odoo 10?

Tags: xml, report, odoo, odoo-10, qweb

How I can create a custom header and footer for my Custom Qweb Report?

I have tried with the explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29808985/how-to-update-default-header-in-pdf-report-qweb), but it doesn't work, maybe it's due to the previous Odoo version.

Is there a way to make this work on Odoo 10?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

### Option 1: Modifying Existent Templates

You can modify the original footer and header views directly:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<odoo>
    <template id="external_layout_header" inherit_id="report.external_layout_header">
        <!-- make here your template modifications as usual -->
    </template>

    <template id="external_layout_footer" inherit_id="account.external_layout_footer">
        <!-- make here your template modifications as usual -->
    </template>
</odoo>
```

The original footer template is this one:

```
<template id="external_layout_footer">
    <div class="footer">
        <div class="text-center" style="border-top: 1px solid black;">
            <ul t-if="not company.custom_footer" class="list-inline">
                <t t-set="company" t-value="company.sudo()"/>
                <li t-if="company.phone">Phone: <span t-field="company.phone"/></li>

                <li t-if="company.fax and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>
                <li t-if="company.fax">Fax: <span t-field="company.fax"/></li>

                <li t-if="company.email and company.fax or company.email and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>
                <li t-if="company.email">Email: <span t-field="company.email"/></li>

                <li t-if="company.website and company.email or company.website and company.fax or company.website and company.phone">&amp;bull;</li>
                <li t-if="company.website">Website: <span t-field="company.website"/></li>
            </ul>

            <ul t-if="not company.custom_footer" class="list-inline" name="financial_infos">
                <li t-if="company.vat">TIN: <span t-field="company.vat"/></li>
            </ul>

            <t t-if="company.custom_footer">
                <span t-raw="company.rml_footer"/>
            </t>

            <ul class="list-inline">
                <li>Page:</li>
                <li><span class="page"/></li>
                <li>/</li>
                <li><span class="topage"/></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>      
</template>
```

And the original header template is this one:

```
<template id="external_layout_header">
    <div class="header">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <img t-if="company.logo" t-att-src="'data:image/png;base64,%s' % company.logo" style="max-height: 45px;"/>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-9 text-right" style="margin-top:20px;" t-field="company.rml_header1"/>
        </div>
        <div class="row zero_min_height">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
                <div style="border-bottom: 1px solid black;"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-6" name="company_address">
                <span t-field="company.partner_id"
                    t-field-options='{"widget": "contact", "fields": ["address", "name"], "no_marker": true}'
                    style="border-bottom: 1px solid black; display:inline-block;"/>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>
```

You can make different footers and headers for different models

```
<t t-if="'model_name' in o and o.model_name == 'account_invoice'">
    <!-- your custom footer or hedaer for invoices -->
</t>
```

### Option 2: Creating some new Custom Footer and Headers

But if you want to use another totally different from these, you will need to create an alternative to the the external layout template:

```
<!-- ORIGINAL -->

<template id="external_layout">
    <!-- Multicompany -->
    <t t-if="not o and doc">
        <t t-set="o" t-value="doc"/>
    </t>
    <t t-if="o and 'company_id' in o">
        <t t-set="company" t-value="o.company_id"></t>
    </t>
    <t t-if="not o or not 'company_id' in o">
        <t t-set="company" t-value="res_company"></t>
    </t>

    <t t-call="report.external_layout_header" />
    <t t-raw="0" />
    <t t-call="report.external_layout_footer" />
</template>

<!-- CUSTOM -->

<template id="custom_external_layout">
    <!-- Multicompany -->
    <t t-if="not o and doc">
        <t t-set="o" t-value="doc"/>
    </t>
    <t t-if="o and 'company_id' in o">
        <t t-set="company" t-value="o.company_id"></t>
    </t>
    <t t-if="not o or not 'company_id' in o">
        <t t-set="company" t-value="res_company"></t>
    </t>

    <t t-call="my_module.custom_external_layout_header" />
    <t t-raw="0" />
    <t t-call="my_module.custom_external_layout_footer" />
</template>
```

And use it in your report template:

```
<template id="your_report_document">
    <t t-call="my_module.custom_external_layout">
        <div class="page">

            <!-- your report content -->

        </div>
    </t>
</template>
```